# Json data has name and color code. how to put these two in html div element

Tags: jquery, html, json

How to visualize json color Key in HTML Div element .I am able to fetch json names to html div. Now i want that name color(info is coming from json data).

here i am sending color code(data.jobs.ibeocloud.culprits[0].color) also from data.json . but i dont know how import that information in html along with the name

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    $("#name").text(data.jobs.ibeocloud.name);
    $("#culpritBranch").text(data.jobs.ibeocloud.culprits[0].branch);
    $("#culpritcolor").text(data.jobs.ibeocloud.culprits[0].color);
    $("#culpritBranch1").text(data.jobs.ibeocloud.culprits[1].branch);
  });
});
```

```css
  section.dashboard-counts .title1 {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #AE0202;
      margin: 0 20px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="title"><span id='culpritName'></span></div>
  <div class="title"><span id='culpritName1'></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
{
      "top10": [
            {
                  "state": "red",
                  "claimed": true,
                  "branch": "release-2.3.4",
                  "job": "sdk",
                  "culprit": "Hansi Meier"
            },
            {
                  "state": "red",
                  "claimed": true,
                  "branch": "master",
                  "job": "ibeo-cloud",
                  "culprit": "Karl Gustavo"
            },
            {
                  "state": "yellow",
                  "claimed": false,
                  "branch": "feature-abc",
                  "job": "appbase",
                  "culprit": "MAfred Auch"
            }
      ],
      "jobs": {
            "ibeocloud": {
                  "name": "ibeo-cloud",
                  "branches": {
                        "master": {
                              "state": "green"
                        },
                        "release": {
                              "state": "yellow",
                              "ratio": {
                                    "green": 2,
                                    "red": 1
                              }
                        },
                        "feature": {
                              "state": "red",
                              "ratio": {
                                    "green": 0,
                                    "red": 1
                              }
                        }
                  },
                  "culprits": [
                        {
                              "branch": "release-1.0.0",
                              "name": "Hansi Meier",
                              "color": "red"
                        },
                        {
                              "branch": "feature-1.0.0",
                              "name": "Karl Gustavo",
                              "color": "blue"
                        }
                  ],
                  "trend": [
                        0,
                        100,
                        50,
                        50,
                        100,
                        100,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                  ],
                  "tests": [
                        [
                              10,
                              20,
                              30,
                              40,
                              50,
                              60,
                              61,
                              65,
                              60,
                              55
                        ],
                        [
                              100,
                              90,
                              80,
                              70,
                              60,
                              50,
                              51,
                              52,
                              53,
                              55
                        ]
                  ],
                  "issues": {
                        "p1": 0,
                        "p2": 11,
                        "p3": 3
                  }
            },
            "appbase": {
                  "name": "appbase",
                  "branches": {
                        "master": {
                              "state": "red"
                        },
                        "release": {
                              "state": "green",
                              "ratio": {
                                    "green": 2,
                                    "red": 0
                              }
                        },
                        "feature": {
                              "state": "yellow",
                              "ratio": {
                                    "green": 1,
                                    "red": 1
                              }
                        }
                  },
                  "culprits": [
                        {
                              "branch": "master",
                              "name": "Hansi Meier"
                        },
                        {
                              "branch": "feature-123",
                              "name": "Manfred Auch"
                        }
                  ],
                  "trend": [
                        100,
                        100,
                        100,
                        100,
                        100,
                        100,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                  ],
                  "tests": [
                        [
                              10,
                              20,
                              30,
                              40,
                              50,
                              60,
                              61,
                              65,
                              60,
                              55
                        ],
                        [
                              100,
                              90,
                              80,
                              70,
                              60,
                              50,
                              51,
                              52,
                              53,
                              55
                        ]
                  ],
                  "issues": {
                        "p1": 0,
                        "p2": 11,
                        "p3": 3
                  }
            }
      },
      "general": {
            "discUsage": 71,
            "slaveUsage": 10
      }
}
```

Comment: you don't have an element with id `culpritBranch`, `culpritBranch1` and `culpritcolor`

Comment: I am having a real difficult time understanding your question are you try to display the branch, name, and color of the culprits array in your html? I am not seeing any kind of loop if that is the case.

Comment: You probably typo "culpritName" with "culpritBranch"

Comment: i dont need any loop here. I am able to display culpritName. what i need is it should be displayed with color which is also culpritcolor

Comment: @gurvinder372       the full html code is like <div class="col-xl-1 col-sm-6">
                <div class="title"><span id='culpritBranch'></span></div>
                <div class="title"><span id='culpritBranch1'></span></div>
                
              </div>

              <div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-6">
                <div class="title"><span id='culpritName'></span></div>
                <div class="title"><span id='culpritName1'></span></div>
              </div>